# Exchange places of "kissing" spheres

Tags: reference-request, discrete-geometry

The [Wikipedia article for *Kissing Number*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kissing_number) says:

> In fact, there is so much extra space that any two of the 12 outer
>   spheres can exchange places through a continuous movement without any
>   of the outer spheres losing contact with the center one.

When and by whom was this proved?  Can someone please name a book or article where this result is explained?

Comment: There's an outline of an argument somewhere in Conway/Sloane's *Sphere Packings, Lattices and Groups*.

Comment: No idea who proved it. There seems to be a proof in Appendix of Chapter 1 in Conway, Sloane's book *sphere packing, lattices and groups* (first ref in wiki's article). If possible, also get hold of Coxeter's book 'Regular Polytopes'. Above appendix refer to some construction found in $\S 8.4$ of Coxeter's book.

Comment: Thanks to both of you.  I'd be happy to accept this as an answer.